# Selenium/Python - continue scrolling down after clicking 'load more'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrape terms from SAP Glossary website with terms details.
I can only get 50 terms now. Because I couldn't figure out how to click on 'load more' then continue scrolling down to scrape more terms.
I noticed the 'load more' button has to change color to orange so it's clickable

```
page_url = "https://help.sap.com/glossary/?locale=en-US&search=CRM"
driver.get(page_url)
driver.maximize_window()
element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value='//a[@role="menuitem"]')
load_more = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='button.motion-button')
detail = []
c = driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME,value='p')
for i in range(51):
    element[i].click()
    detail.append(c[0].text)
    print(i,c[0].text)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this video talks exactly what I need. It's not about the 'Load more' button...you need to find the json file
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqNufBruvUc

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code can meet your requirement, first while the 'load more' button is existed, click it to load more data. after all data loaded. then use 'find_elements' to get the element collection.

```
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()
tab = cc.chrome.open("https://help.sap.com/glossary/?locale=en-US&search=CRM")
load_more = tab.find_element_by_css_selector('button.motion-button')
while tab.is_existing_by_css_selector('button.motion-button'):
    load_more.click()
    sleep(1)

elements = tab.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@role="menuitem"]')
for element in elements:
    element.click()
    print(element.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! I think using the hidden json file is easier for this case.